# Adjust Padding on Navigation Border - Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to tighten the border under the navigation menu. This is the CSS code I have:

CSS:

```
li.current_page_item a {
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 3px;
  border-style:solid;
  line-height: 0;
  border-bottom-color:green;
}
```

My website http://www.verbatimagency.com

Comment: I think you actually need to reduce the `padding-bottom` property for your `a` tags in the menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
li.current_page_item a {
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px;
  border-style:solid;
  line-height: 0;
  border-bottom-color:green;
  line-height: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

li.current_page_item {
  line-height: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

It was the `padding-bottom` on the `<a>` tag. See the corrected preview:

[image]

You may need to adjust it accordingly.

Comment: Works perfectly but not for the blog page? Must be a function issue?

Comment: Could be. Where did you put the CSS? @CallMeNicholi...

Comment: I put it in the child CSS. @PraveenKumar

Comment: @CallMeNicholi Can you try using the `!important` in this?

Comment: For some reason when I added the blog to the menu, it added as a link and not a page. Very odd. So I re-added it. Works fine. Thanks! @PraveenKumar

Comment: @CallMeNicholi Glad it works for you. Would you mind accepting my answer?